# Query data using pandas with kwargs

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-analysis, keyword-argument

I'm trying to Query data using python pandas library. here is an example json of the data...

```
[
{
"name": "Bob", 
"city": "NY", 
"status": "Active"
}, 
{
"name": "Jake", 
"city": "SF", 
"status": "Active" 
}, 
{
"name": "Jill", 
"city": "NY", 
"status": "Lazy" 
},
{
"name": "Steve", 
"city": "NY", 
"status": "Lazy" 
}]
```

My goal is to query the data where city == NY and status == Lazy.
One way using pandas DataFrame is to do...

```
df = df[(df.status == "Lazy") & (df.city == "NY")]
```

This is working fine but i wanted this to be more abstract.

This there way I can use **kwargs to filter the data? so far i've had trouble using Pandas documentation.

so far I've done.....

```
 def main(**kwargs):

        readJson = pd.read_json(sys.argv[1])

        for key,value in kwargs.iteritems():
            print(key,value)
            readJson = readJson[readJson[key] == value]

        print readJson

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(status="Lazy",city="NY")
```

again...this works just fine, but I wonder if there is some better way to do it.

Comment: came across this many times myself and decided to solve it once and for all... see  [pandas-dfquery](https://github.com/miraculixx/pandas-dfquery), it basically does what you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see anything wrong with your approach.  If you wanted to use `df.query` you could do something like this, although I'd argue it's less readable.

```
expr = " and ".join(k + "=='" + v + "'" for (k,v) in kwargs.items())
readJson = readJson.query(expr)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kwargs is nothing really to do with Pandas, it is a basic Python thing, you simply need to make a function that accepts Kwargs and substitute the variable Kwargs into the pandas Df query statement (inside the function). Don't have the time to code it for you but reading the Python docs should get you going. Pandas is but one great part of the Python system, when you start to combine multiple parts you will need to get familiar with those pieces.

Comment: yes I know what **kwargs is... I'm having trouble trying to get to work with pandas Df query. thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: so show us what you have tried and what errors you may be getting and then we can help.

Comment: FWIW does not look like you were interested at all in the DF query methods and Pandas Functionality other than Json read, which is fine but that is why it is important to show what you have done :-)